# Can high frequency AC show as DC on a multimeter?

Tags: ac, dc, frequency, multimeter

If a high frequency AC (4kHz) is measured with the DC option on a multimeter, will it show a DC value?

Comment: No. It will not.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm not sure- I can imagine where something in a cheap multimeter could act as a detector and cause a high-frequency AC signal to give a DC reading.  I've never seen it, and of course it would depend on the specific multimeter but I guess it's possible?

Comment: @JohnD I can think of no mechanism that would cause that in any DC measurement method *especially* dual slope which multimeters tend to use.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was thinking of some input protection circuitry parasitics acting as a rectifier/peak detector, but since we can't know what the circuitry is like in every multimeter out there it's hard to know what might happen.  I know it will definitely NOT read an AC signal as DC on a good quality meter.

Comment: Depends on the multimeter but most won’t.

Comment: What kind of multimeter and what kind of AC? Is it 4 kHz sine wave, or square wave, and if square wave, does it have 50% duty or something else?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be possible if you grossly overload the input on some multimeters. Trying a 7V RMS 400Hz sine wave into a Fluke handheld and a Uni-T handheld, the Fluke showed only a 14mV offset that was symmetrical when the leads were reversed so presumably a real offset in the arb function generator. Consistent over ranges down to 200mV F.S.

The Uni-T on the 2V range behaved similarly but on the 200mV range it triggered an overload protection (audible alarm) and showed an asymmetrical voltage in the 25mV range. that was positive for either polarity of input.